# While loop in Haskell with a condition

Tags: loops, haskell, while-loop

I'm having a little Haskell Situation over here. I'm trying to write two functions with monads.
First one is supposed to iterate through a function as long as the condition is true for the input / output of the function. Second one is supposed to use the first one to take a number as input and write it as output until you enter a space.

I'm stuck with this, any help?

```
module Test where

while :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> IO a) -> a -> IO a
while praed funktion x = do
                         f <- praed (funktion x)
                         if f == True then do
                                             y <- funktion x
                                             while praed funktion y
                         else return x



power2 :: IO ()
power2 = do putStr (Please enter a number.")
            i <- getChar
            while praed funktion
            where praed x = if x /= ' ' then False else True
                  funktion = i
```

Comment: So which one of these is your question about? Where are you stuck, what doesn't work?

Comment: Both of these functions don't even compile yet, and I'm pretty sure they wouldn't do what I want them to do anyways. I just don't know how to write it in a working version. I'm basically trying to get a while loop working with a condition. So for example, 
`while odd (square 3)` 
should test if square 3 is odd, then use the result of square 3 = 9 and do
`while odd (square 9)` and so on and on.

Technically it shouldn't need an x, it should just work with
`while condition function`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
import Control.Monad

while :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> IO a) -> a -> IO a
while praed funktion x
    | praed x   = do
        y <- funktion x
        while praed funktion y
    | otherwise = return x


power2 :: IO ()
power2 = do
    putStr "Please enter a number."
    i <- getChar
    let praed x = x /= ' '
    let f x = do
        putChar x
        getChar
    while praed f '?'
    return ()
```

Some notes:

- Using `if x then True else False` is redundant, it's equivalent to just `x`.
- Similarly `if x == True ...` is redundant and equivalent to `if x ...`.
- You need to distinguish between `IO` actions and their results. For example, if yo do

  ```
  do
      i <- getChar
      ...
  ```

  then in ... `i` represents the result of the action, a character, so `i :: Char`. But `getChar :: IO Char` is the action itself. You can view it as a recipe that returns `Char` when performed. You can pass the recipe around to functions etc., and it is only performed when executed somewhere.
- Your `while` called `funktion` twice, which probably isn't what you intend - it would read a character twice, check the first one and return the second one. Remember, your `funktion` is an action, so each time you "invoke" the action (for example by using `<- funktion ...` in the `do` notation), the action is run again. So it should rather be something like

  ```
  do
      y <- funktion x
      f <- praed y
      -- ...
  ```

  (My code is somewhat different, it checks the argument that is passed to it.)

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I understand how you did power2, makes a lot of sense. I'm still not sure what exactly is happening in while, tho. At which point exactly does praed check if the condition is true?

Comment: @Chris It checks if the condition holds for its argument of type `a` before doing anything else, just like `while` statements in functional languages do. This is done using [guards](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#guards-guards), which is often preferable over `if/then/else`. The line `| praed x   = do ...` says _if the condition `praed x` is true, proceed with ..._. The next line `| otherwise = ...` covers all the rest cases (because `otherwise` is just a synonym for `True`, so `otherwise` is a condition that is always satisfied).

Comment: `if x then True else False` isn't quite equivalent to `x`, it's equivalent to `(x :: Bool)` though

Answer (score 4):

For a pure version:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

while :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
while p f = go where go !x = if p x then go (f x) else x

test1 :: Int
test1 = while (< 1000) (* 2) 2
-- test1 => 1024
```

for monadic:

```
import Control.Monad

whileM :: (Monad m, MonadPlus f) => (a -> m Bool) -> m a -> m (f a)
whileM p f = go where
  go = do
    x <- f
    r <- p x
    if r then (return x `mplus`) `liftM` go else return mzero

test2 :: IO [String]
test2 = whileM (return . (/= "quit")) getLine
-- *Main> test2
-- quit
-- []
-- *Main> test2
-- 1
-- 2
-- 3
-- quit
-- ["1","2","3"]

power2 :: IO (Maybe Char)
power2 = whileM (return . (/= 'q')) getChar
-- *Main> power2
-- q
-- Nothing
-- *Main> power2
-- 1
-- 2
-- 3
-- q
-- Just '\n'
```

see also:

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-loops, http://hackage.haskell.org/package/loop-while, http://hackage.haskell.org/package/control-monad-loop.

http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/01/haskell-for-c-programmers-for-loops.html

Comment: Another pure version)
`while p = until (not . p)`