# While loop in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I want to create a while loop to concatenate strings in the `xs` list 
until I find an empty string, but it seems neither we have a chance to 
increment an Int nor create a while loop.

So this looks like a pseudo code for Haskell, but how can I actually implement my solution?

```
prt :: String -> [String] -> Int -> String
prt str xs x = do
         while((xs !! (x)) /= "")
         str = str ++ (xs !! (x++))
```

Comment: Related: [While loop in Haskell with a condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17719620/while-loop-in-haskell-with-a-condition)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Forget array indexes: they are often not needed. All you have to do for your task is getting the longest prefix of your list containing only non-empty strings.

```
takeWhile (not . null) xs
-- or
takeWhile (/= "") xs
```

Then you want to concatenate these strings.

```
concat $ takeWhile (/= "") xs
```

If you want to start after `n` strings for some reason, just drop the first `n` before beginning:

```
concat $ takeWhile (/= "") $ drop n xs
```

---

If you really want to do a custom "loop", use recursion:

```
g xs n = f $ drop n xs
f []      = ""
f ("":xs) = ""
f (x:xs)  = x ++ f xs
```

Comment: If I understand his pseudocode correctly, he wants to do this, but starting at index `x`: maybe add a `drop` in there or something?

Comment: @MichaelRawson I added that, although I believe the string and index parameters could be added by the OP while attempting to make a loop -- it is possible that they don't really need those arguments.

Comment: Yes that is one problem I have to handle

Comment: @coderbst, note that the first expression, `not . null`, should generally be preferred to `(/= "")` because it works for types other than strings.