# Haskell getLine in a function's otherwise

Tags: function, haskell, input

I'm really new to Haskell and am trying to learn some simple functions.

I made some option choices through functions like so:

```
displayOptions :: Int -> String
displayOptions option
    | option == 0 = "1 - Shop\n2 - Fight Monsters\n3 - Inn\n4 - Monk"
    | otherwise = "invalid"
```

I then get the user input with `getLine`

```
choice <- getLine
```

And then I display a second option box for example,

```
playerChoice :: String -> String
playerChoice option
    | option == "1" = "Sword - 50gp\nShield - 100gp"
    | option == "2" = "You go fight some monsters outside town."
    | option == "3" = "You go to the town Inn."
    | option == "4" = "You go see the holy monk."
    | otherwise = "You entered invalid information...\n" ++ displayOptions(0)
```

What I'm confused about is how I can get the user's choice again within a function.  I want my `otherwise =` to say invalid information, display the options, get the input again and then display the choice they made.

So my main program would look something like this:

```
main = do
    putStrLn "The king has sent you on the journey to become a master."
    putStrLn $ "What would you like to do?"
    putStrLn $ displayOptions(0)
    choice <- getLine
    putStrLn $ playerChoice(choice)
```

Comment: Can you please provide a complete program to illustrate what you are asking about?

Comment: I updated with my main for more clarity hopefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to change the return type to be IO String instead of String.

However, probably you want to return Either String String so the function indicates that it's returned the game progression text `Right "You do something"` or a failure with an explanation of the failure `Left "Not an option"`.

Then in the caller you loop until you get a `Right` value and each time you get a `Left` value you print the text and ask again.

I'm sure there's a slightly better way but here's some quickly fixed up code:

```
module Main where

playerChoice :: String -> Either String String
playerChoice option
    | option == "1" = Right "Sword - 50gp\nShield - 100gp"
    | option == "2" = Right "You go fight some monsters outside town."
    | option == "3" = Right "You go to the town Inn."
    | option == "4" = Right "You go see the holy monk."
    | otherwise = Left "You entered invalid information..."

displayOptions :: Int -> String
displayOptions option
    | option == 0 = "1 - Shop\n2 - Fight Monsters\n3 - Inn\n4 - Monk\n"
    | otherwise = "invalid"

main = do
    let progress whathappens = do
        putStrLn whathappens
        let tryAsk prompt = do
            putStrLn prompt
            choice <- getLine
            either tryAsk progress $ playerChoice(choice)
        tryAsk $ displayOptions(0) ++ "What would you like to do?"
    progress "The king has sent you on the journey to become a master."
```

if you `import Data.Function` then you can also write it like the following - which in this case probably isn't better but it's a nice shallow step into a fascinating part of haskell:

```
fix (\moreProgress whathappens -> do
    putStrLn whathappens
    fix (\askAgain prompt -> do
        putStrLn prompt
        choice <- getLine
        either askAgain moreProgress $ playerChoice(choice))
        $ displayOptions(0) ++ "What would you like to do?")
    $ "The king has sent you on the journey to become a master."
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You should change the return type to `Either String String` in order to provide an error message. For more details, look at the docs for the `Either` type.
2. In Haskell, we don't have traditional looping structures like `for` or `while` instead we use recursive calls. See [While loop in Haskell with a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17719620/while-loop-in-haskell-with-a-condition) for an example.